# Entity Framework and SQL Server 2014

Tags: entity-framework

Are there any plans to add support for the new features in SQL Server 2014 (namely in-memory OLTP) in the next version(s) of Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect your Entity Framework (EF) application to a database that has the new memory-optimized tables. The main things you need to look out for is [dealing with retries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169141.aspx). 
Also, to get the most out of in-memory OLTP [you will want to use natively compiled stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133184.aspx). It is possible to use stored procs in EF, but I guess it's not the default.

At this stage entity framework itself does not support generating memory-optimized tables from code. This is something we are thinking about for a future version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the retries related warning, I'll add these new error codes in my retry logic now.

Comment: Honestly, I still don't know what to make out of the new natively compiled stored procedures... On one hand they'd be great for batch processing, but for business logic - not so much. Business logic does not belong in the data tier in at least 90% of the applications. Improving performance is great but I wish MS had a better answer to the scalability problems addressed by the big data/NoSQL DB-s.

Comment: @Valo here is a great explanation of the benefits of this tech, its faster to aggregate large data than passing all the data to C# for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn452287.aspx